# Resizable split screen divs using jquery UI

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I have a design in mind that involves a split panel view in html, similar to a winforms split panel.  I've been expirimenting with [jQuery UI - Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable) and I like the function, I just can't seem to co-ordinate the resizing of the two `div`s.  The problem with the current code is that the two `div`s resize away from each other, not with one following the other.  How can I make the two `div`s work together?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/superfish.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" media="screen">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/superfish.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


        // initialise plugins
        $(function(){
            try {
                $('ul.sf-menu').superfish();

                //set up divs
                $('#Content').resizable({ handles: 'e', alsoResize: $('#Attributes')});

            }catch(ex){
                alert(ex.message);
            }
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="Header">
            <div id="Menu">
                <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
                    <!-- Snip menu -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Middle">
            <div id="Content" class="ui-widget-content">This is where the view is.<br/>
            Imagine an image here ...
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            </div>
            <div id="Attributes" class="ui-widget-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="FootBreak"/>
        <div id="Footer">
            <a href="#">Help</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting something like style="display:inline;float:left/(right for the other)" ?

Comment: @asawyer, yes.  They are sticking to the sides of the screen, but div2 isn't resizing ...

Comment: Related: [Split pane using CSS3 Resize property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758728/split-pane-using-css3-resize-property), same effect, except I need it to work in IE.  I will settle for solutions other than jQuery, I just thought it best b/c it's already browser independent (mostly).

Answer (score 5):

I have worked out a reasonable hack, using the resize event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var WIDTH_ATTR = 'initWidth';

    // initialise plugins
    $(function(){
        try {
            $('#Content').resizable({ handles: 'e', resize: resizeAttr }); 
            $('#Content').attr(WIDTH_ATTR, $('#Content').width());
            $('#InfoPanel').attr(WIDTH_ATTR, $('#InfoPanel').width());
        }catch(ex){
            alert(ex.message);
        }
    });

    function resizeAttr(event, ui){
        var change = ui.size.width - $('#Content').attr(WIDTH_ATTR);
        $('#InfoPanel').width($('#InfoPanel').attr(WIDTH_ATTR) - change);
    };

</script>
```

<sub>I'm still open to cleaner answers from others...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this meets the requirements, but ExtJS handles split panes with ease and works cross-browser. For example, see this [RSS feed client in ExtJS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/feed-viewer/view.html). Be aware the ExtJS has commercial licensing restrictions if your intent is to sell your product.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a horizontal split (one top div, one bottom div), maybe slightly more minimalistic:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">1st</div> 
    <div id="div2">2nd</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#div1, #div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  outline: solid 1px #ccc; /* just for making the divs visible */
  margin: 5px; /* just for making the divs visible */
}
#div1 {
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
#div2 {
  top: 110px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#div1').resizable({
  handles: 's',
  resize: resizeEventHandler
});
function resizeEventHandler(event, ui){
  var new_height = ui.size.height;
  $('#div2').css('top', new_height + 10);
}
```

[See demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/519034/).