# jQuery UI and Splitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, portlet

Using jQuery UI, how can I use a Splitter kind of feature like the one at 
http://methvin.com/splitter/3csplitter.html?

I am asking this as I need 2 things to be implemented on my page;
Portlet (Draggable) :: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets
and Vertical Splitter :: http://methvin.com/splitter/3csplitter.html

I am not sure how good coding practice it is if I am including 2 separate libraries (even though both are jQuery based);
like http://host.sonspring.com/portlets/ for Portlets
and http://methvin.com/splitter/3csplitter.html for Splitter

Comment: it provides resizable. you can implement the splitter using that. Also check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199368/resizable-split-screen-divs-using-jquery-ui)

Comment: I needed a splitter similar to http://methvin.com/splitter/3csplitter.html

Answer (score 18):

Here is an example on how to create the splitter using jQuery UI:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="resizable resizable1"></div>
    <div class="resizable resizable2"></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function () 
{
    $(".resizable1").resizable(
    {
        autoHide: true,
        handles: 'e',
        resize: function(e, ui) 
        {
            var parent = ui.element.parent();
            var remainingSpace = parent.width() - ui.element.outerWidth(),
                divTwo = ui.element.next(),
                divTwoWidth = (remainingSpace - (divTwo.outerWidth() - divTwo.width()))/parent.width()*100+"%";
                divTwo.width(divTwoWidth);
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) 
        {
            var parent = ui.element.parent();
            ui.element.css(
            {
                width: ui.element.width()/parent.width()*100+"%",
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is a popular script. I've added little modifications for the fluid layout.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/86/)

Comment: Hahah.  I've been looking for this script ALL DAY!  Thanks.

Comment: Using Firefox 32.0.1, the blue box wraps to the next line when resizing. To prevent that, replace the commas with individual `var` declarations starting at `var remainingSpace = ...`

Comment: Also, I found that the following two css lines were required to get it to work: `.ui-resizable { position: relative;}` and `.ui-resizable-handle { position: absolute;font-size: 0.1px; display: block; }`

Answer (score 2):

I used Dmitriy's answer as the base of my implementation. Note that there is nothing stopping that particular implementation from doubling the bounding box when the slider is dragged to the right.

I needed a simple non-moveable splitter for now (with the view to making the panes resizable in the future), and my application is already using jQuery, so I achieved this by changing part of his code as follows:

```
$(function () 
{
    $(".resizable1").resizable(
    {
        autoHide: false,
        containment: "#wrap",
        ...
```

I also changed the css cursor style (among other things) to prevent the resizable cursor from being displayed as follows:

```
.ui-resizable-e { 
    cursor: default; 
    ...
```

Thanks Dmitriy!

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was: first you select all the boxes except the last.  Those get a splitter to their right side.
Then, when the splitter is moved, only the two boxes touching the splitter are resized.

This is an example you can copy paste; it works as is.
This can be used for any number of columns; just make sure you also adapt the css.

I added some buttons to expand 1 box; also a reset button.

```js
$(function () {
        // settings
        var minWidth = 15;
        var splitterWidth = 10;  // this sh ould match the css value

        var splitter   =  $('.ui-resizable-e');
        var container =   $('.wrap');
        var boxes =       $('.resizable');

        var subBoxWidth = 0;


        $(".resizable:not(:last)").resizable({
          autoHide: false,
          handles: 'e',
          minWidth: minWidth,

          start: function(event, ui) {
            // We will take/give width from/to the next element; leaving all other divs alone.
            subBoxWidth = ui.element.width() + ui.element.next().width();
            // set maximum width
            ui.element.resizable({
              maxWidth: subBoxWidth - splitterWidth - minWidth
            });
          },

          resize: function(e, ui) {
            var index = $('.wrap').index( ui.element );
            ui.element.next().width(
              subBoxWidth - ui.element.width()
            );
          },

        });
        // collapses all the other boxes to the minimum width; expands the chosen box to what ever width is left
        $('.expand').click(function () {
          var index = $(this).data('index');
          var boxesToCollapse = boxes.length - 1;
          var widthLeft = container.width() - boxesToCollapse * (minWidth + splitterWidth);
          for (var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
            boxes.eq(i).width( i==index ? widthLeft : minWidth);
          }
        });
        $('.reset').click(function () {
          boxes.removeAttr('style');
        });
      });
```

```css
body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .wrap {
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        background-color: #c0c0c0;
      }
      .resizable {
          width: 25%;
          height: 120px;
          display: inline-block;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      .ui-resizable-e { 
          cursor: e-resize; 
          width: 10px; 
          top: 0; 
          bottom: 0; 
          background-color: gray;
          z-index: 10;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<div class="wrap">
      <div class="resizable"> HELLO  </div>
      <div class="resizable"> WORLD </div>
      <div class="resizable"> FOO </div>
      <div class="resizable"> BAR </div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
      <input type="button" value="expand 0" data-index="0" class="expand">
      <input type="button" value="expand 1" data-index="1" class="expand">
      <input type="button" value="expand 2" data-index="2" class="expand">
      <input type="button" value="expand 3" data-index="3" class="expand">
      <input type="button" value="reset" class="reset">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Splitter component](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/splitter/basic-usage) part of the Shield UI framework allows you to use a mixture of horizontal and vertical splitters.