# jQuery UI Splitter/Resizable for unlimited amount of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Using jQueryUI Splitter or Resizable functions I want to create a layout that allows an unlimited amount of columns to be added and all columns need to be resizable.

So it is like this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f3gLh3mw/

But in this fiddle the HTML contains out of nested sets instead of inline. Which limits the possibilities as with the above fiddle you can only have equal widths for 2,4,8,16,32 etc columns. Everything in between shows up crooked as you can see in the Fiddle.

When researching this I came on this SO question: [jQuery UI and Splitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309163/jquery-ui-and-splitter)

If you look at the top answer then it shows a structure like:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="resizable resizable1"></div>
  <div class="resizable resizable2"></div>
</div>
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/86/

Which is the structure I want but the Javascript is hardcoded for only 2 resizable items.

So here is the question:

How to modify the last fiddle so it works with any amount of `.resizable` divs.

Or does anyone know of a plugin that can do this.

Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I found this plugin: http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/

Which does exactly what is says and is very close to the functionality that I want. Only it is in a table layout and not a div layout.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2h4kLzgj/6/

It is activated by this:

```
$("#sample2").colResizable({
  fixed:true,
  liveDrag:true,
  gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>", 
  draggingClass:"dragging" });
```